# Implementing RNN with flax.nn.Module

Tags: python, deep-learning, module, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to implement a basic RNN cell with `flax.nn.Module`. the equations to implement the RNN cell are quite simple:

> a_t = W * h_{t-1} + U * x_t + b

> h_t = tanh(a_t)

> o_t = V * h_t + c

where h_t is the updated state at time t, x_t is the input and o_t is the output and Tanh is our activation function.

My code uses `flax.nn.Module`,

```
class ElmanCell(nn.Module):
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, h, x):
    nextState = jnp.tanh(jnp.dot(W, h) * jnp.dot(U, x) + b)
    return nextState
```

I don't know hoe to implement the parameters W, U and b. Are they supposed to be attributes of nn.Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class RNNCell(nn.Module):
  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, state, x):
    # Wh @ h + Wx @ x + b can be efficiently computed
    # by concatenating the vectors and then having a single dense layer
    x = np.concatenate([state, x])
    new_state = np.tanh(nn.Dense(state.shape[0])(x))
    return new_state
```

This way the parameters will be learned. See https://schmit.github.io/jax/2021/06/20/jax-language-model-rnn.html